# When joined to a corporate domain, how does Windows know to display the name of the domain when connected to the network?

Tags: windows, networking, domain, windows-domain

For Windows computers that are connected to corporate networks - either physically via Ethernet or via Wi-Fi/VPN, I've noticed that the machine is aware of the domain of the network. As an example, if connected directly in the System Tray it may say something along the lines of "example.com Internet Access".

How does Windows know when its connected to the domain in this way - how does it associate the network that it's connected to with the "example.com" hostname?

Comment: What exactly do you need this information for? Is there a problem? What do you mean by "if connected directly in the System Tray"?? What do you mean by "how does it associate the network that it's connected to with the "example.com" hostname?"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows know that you are connected to the domain through your login which is s.th. like `domainname.local\username` (and not `.\username` which would be a local account).

Not sure what you mean by

> how does it associate the network that it's connected to with the
> "example.com" hostname?

But in general the domain controller will be (by default) your domain server which manages DNS names. So whatever domain you are using (in your case "example.com") it will have the IP adresses for the devices on it's domain.